# TCP client waits after establishing the connection

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I have an HTTP server and a client (I use curl for testing). The problem I have is that even the simplest, "ping" request takes 3-5 seconds to accomplish. I have run tcpdump on the server and it seems that after establishing TCP connection, the client (curl) waits 3-4 seconds for sending the HTTP request:

> 09:06:55.079376 IP client > server: Flags [S], seq 1639466412, win 64240, options [mss 1358,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
>
> 09:06:55.079457 IP server > client: Flags [S.], seq 2519785093, ack 1639466413, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
>
> 09:06:55.087145 IP client > server: Flags [.], ack 1, win 1029, length 0
>
> 09:06:59.722060 IP client > server: Flags [P.], seq 1:83, ack 1, win 1029, length 82: HTTP: GET /ping HTTP/1.1

You can see the problem between 3 and 4 line of the tcpdump output.

Do you know what can cause this issue? Is this really on the client side or I should check also on the server side?

**UPDATE**
If I use telnet to connect to the server's port and send GET, the server replies immediately.

Answer (score 0):

- `Flags [S]` Syn
- `Flags [S.]` - Syn Ack
- `Flags [.]` - Placeholder, usually used for ACK.
- `Flags [P.]` - Push Ack
- Can you prepend `time` to your curl command? as shown below.
- These hosts, is there latency between the two?

As a test on the same host (terminal):

`terminal a` $ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8989

`terminal b` $ time curl -vvv localhost:8989
results look something like:

```
real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.006s
sys     0m0.005s
```

At this point its hard to say if this is client or server side, this depends on the data you are attempting to query. Can you share that query/curl command?